# flask-stormpath group creation

Tags: python, flask, authorization, stormpath

I have created a Python application using Flask-Stormpath and am following the documentation to create groups for authentication.  Prior to adding the 5 lines of group creation code the program runs perfectly.  Now when I compile the following code (showing just the first part of app.py in this case):

```
from os import environ

from flask import Flask, session, request, jsonify, g, abort, url_for, redirect, render_template, g, flash, escape
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin

from flask_stormpath import StormpathManager, User, login_required, login_user, logout_user, user, groups_required
from stormpath.error import Error as StormpathError
from datetime import timedelta

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/static')

CORS(app)

app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = environ.get('SECRET_KEY', 'this_should_be_configured')
app.config['STORMPATH_API_KEY_ID'] = environ.get('STORMPATH_API_KEY_ID')
app.config['STORMPATH_API_KEY_SECRET'] = environ.get('STORMPATH_API_KEY_SECRET')
app.config['STORMPATH_APPLICATION'] = environ.get('STORMPATH_APPLICATION')
app.config['STORMPATH_APPLICATION_HREF'] = environ.get('STORMPATH_APPLICATION_HREF')
app.config['STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_ID'] = environ.get('STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_ID')
app.config['STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_SECRET'] = environ.get('STORMPATH_CLIENT_APIKEY_SECRET')
app.config['STORMPATH_URL'] = environ.get('STORMPATH_URL')
app.config['STORMPATH_ENABLE_LOGIN'] = False
app.config['STORMPATH_ENABLE_REGISTRATION'] = False
app.config['STORMPATH_ENABLE_LOGOUT'] = False

app.config['STORMPATH_COOKIE_DURATION'] = timedelta(minutes=60)

stormpath_manager = StormpathManager(app)
stormpath_manager.login_view = '.login'

# Code to add groups to the application
directory = stormpath_manager.application.default_account_store_mapping.account_store
guests = directory.groups.create({'name': 'guests'})
members = directory.groups.create({'name': 'members'})
managers = directory.groups.create({'name': 'managers'})
admins = directory.groups.create({'name': 'admins'})
```

I now get a compilation error from within the Stormpath library:

> (venv) Marks-MacBook-Pro-2:flask_heroku markschulz$ python app.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "app.py", line 41, in 
>       directory = stormpath_manager.application.default_account_store_mapping.account_store
>     File "/Users/markschulz/Projects/maid2match/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_stormpath/**init**.py", line 266, in application
>       ctx = stack.top.app
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'app'

What do I need to do to get past this error?  The code line for 'directory' is taken directly from the Stormpath documentation.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

This answer does not work for cases where you are building "a simple application specific admin panel as part of the app so that a business admin type can use."

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

You should use the Stormpath admin panel to achieve this. Once you log into your Stormpath account:

**TO CREATE A GROUP**

1. Click the `Groups` button in the navbar.
2. Click the `Create a Group` button.
3. Select a directory, and enter a name and description.

See [here](https://docs.stormpath.com/console/product-guide/latest/getting-started.html#add-a-group) for more detailed steps (with images).

**TO ADD AN ACCOUNT TO A GROUP**

Click the `Groups` button in the navbar.

Click `Accounts` on the left hand menu.

Click `Add Existing Account` and select the account to be added to the group.

See [here](https://docs.stormpath.com/console/product-guide/latest/getting-started.html#add-an-account-to-the-group) for more detailed steps (with images).

Comment: I agree that this is the way to go for group management by an IT admin type.  With this code I am looking to build a simple application specific admin panel as part of the app so that a business admin type can use.  I wouldn't want to let some of these types loose in the full Stormpath Admin panel.  BTW I heard from Stormpath support on API support for group management and of course they stated the obvious: documentation for this is in the Python documentation and not the Python-Flask documentation. Still need to RTFM.

Comment: Good point. The flask apps I've built have been for IT admin types so I did not consider cases involving business admin types. When you figure this out be sure to add an answer here, I'm now curious about how to get that to work!